# How to get base url only from textfile in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text

I have a text file which have multiple urls with detail paths i want to get only base urls using regex

Text file contain urls like this

```
www.facbook.com/abc/xyz
www.google.com.pk/q=12hsjak
www.yahoo.co.uk/avga/ajak
defence.pk/zya/bahawalpur
Pic2fly.uk/abc
```

Want output like this

```
Www.facebook.com
Www.google.com.pk
Www.yahoo.co.uk
Defence.pk
Pic2fly.uk
```

Please help

I have tried this

```
Print re.search(r'(https?://)?(www\.)?([^/]*)', url)[3]
```

Comment: Did you tried something? What doesn't work?

Comment: Yes i have added in the question

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need re for this, try [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) or [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: Don't use `os.path.split`. That's the wrong tool for the job, even if it works on some/most/all operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep all URLs with ('/') inside, into a list, then would search the list like this:

```
list1=['www.facbook.com/abc/xyz','www.google.com.pk/q=12hsjak','www.yahoo.co.uk/avga/ajak','defence.pk/zya/bahawalpur','Pic2fly.uk/abc']
i=0
while i<len(list1):
    print(list1[i][:list1[i].find('/')])
    i+=1
```

result is what you want, like this:

```
www.facbook.com
www.google.com.pk
www.yahoo.co.uk
defence.pk
Pic2fly.uk
```